# Why is this texture being loaded multiple times in AFrame?

Tags: aframe

I have this asset definition:

```
<a-asset-item id="DNA"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    src="https://cdn.glitch.com/2dd120f4-5d77-403f-af9d-feb8e33ed767%2FAR_DNA.dae">
</a-asset-item>
```

And this reference in my scene:

```
<a-entity collada-model="#DNA"
position="-60 0 0" 
scale="2 2 2" 
rotation="0 90 0" model-monitor></a-entity>
```

When I look at the network window in my browser console, I'm seeing the asset being downloaded twice. And it's 12 mb.
[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: is it happening if You don't declare it in the assets, and load the model inline via collada-model="dna.dae" ? – Piotr Adam Milewski 10 hours ago